# How to override items in ArrayList on Android

Tags: android, list, kotlin, arraylist

In my application I should send some data to server.
This data generate with users.
I should add this items to ArrayList, then send to server on **Body** with `Retrofit`.

I write below codes, and I can added items to `ArrayList`.
But users maybe update this data.
**For example :** first time set 3 , and another time set 5 !

But show me two items!

I want override 5 to 3!

**My log cat :**

```
E/evaluationLog: [Evaluation(evaluationId=4, score=3), Evaluation(evaluationId=3, score=4), Evaluation(evaluationId=4, score=1), Evaluation(evaluationId=4, score=4)]
```

I have **four** items, **three** items for **evaluationId=4** and **one** for **evaluationId=3**.

I want override this 3 items on **evaluationId=4** and just set lasted item!

I want just show me such as this :

```
E/evaluationLog: [Evaluation(evaluationId=3, score=4), Evaluation(evaluationId=4, score=4)]
```

**My codes :**

```
    private val evaluationSubmitScoreList: MutableList<BodyModelSubmitRate.Evaluation> = mutableListOf()
    
        @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
        fun onEvaluation(event: EventsEvaluationStaff.OnEvaluation) {
                evaluationSubmitScoreList.add(BodyModelSubmitRate.Evaluation(event.id, event.score))

}
```

**With below code, I can see my list items :**

```
submit.setOnClickListener {
            if (!isEmptyString(comment.text.toString())) {
                Log.e("evaluationLog", evaluationBody.evaluations.toString())
            } else {
                comment.error = getString(R.string.notEmptyThisField)
            }
        }
```

How can I it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The items are added in the list because you are using `evaluationSubmitScoreList.add()` function. You need to maybe search the item on the list based on the event.id passed and replace the value of the item at that index. for example:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
fun onEvaluation(event: EventsEvaluationStaff.OnEvaluation) {
int index = -1
for(int i=0; i<evaluationSubmitScoreList.size; i++){
    BodyModelSubmitRate.Evaluation eval = evaluationSubmitScoreList[i];
    if(eval.id == event.id){
        index=i;
        break;
    }
}
if(index== -1){
      evaluationSubmitScoreList.add(BodyModelSubmitRate.Evaluation(event.id, event.score))
} else {
     evaluationSubmitScoreList.set(index, BodyModelSubmitRate.Evaluation(event.id, event.score));
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know which item is duplicated! can you send to me code?

Comment: Thanks my friend for update your code. but I don't know how can I find which index is dupicated! coy help me for this?

Comment: i have updated the code. this way you can check for unique values in a list and update it

Comment: Thanks dear, but not work correctly! please see this log : `E/evaluationLog: [Evaluation(evaluationId=17, score=2)]
E/evaluationLog: [Evaluation(evaluationId=17, score=2), Evaluation(evaluationId=3, score=4)]
E/evaluationLog: [Evaluation(evaluationId=17, score=2), Evaluation(evaluationId=3, score=4), Evaluation(evaluationId=5, score=3)]
E/evaluationLog: [Evaluation(evaluationId=17, score=2), Evaluation(evaluationId=17, score=4), Evaluation(evaluationId=5, score=3)]`

Comment: try it with the break; check updated code.